# How to create a regex for following condition?

Tags: c#, regex

I was creating a regex for following condition

a string can contain any alphabet, digit and ' and ? 
the string should start with either alphabet or digit

for ex:

```
adsfj
asfj's
jfkd'sdf?
df
ds?
afjdk?
```

are all valid

I use C# 2.0

I tried something like this

```
  ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[']\*[a-zA-Z0-9]\*[?]\*[a-zA-Z0-9]\*$
```

which did not solve the problem.... any idea..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simpler than you made it: `^[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d'?]*$`

```
^            # Start of string anchor.
[a-zA-Z\d]   # First character is a letter or a digit.
[a-zA-Z\d'?] # Subsequent characters are letters, digits, apostrophes or question marks...
*            # ...repeated any number of times.
$            # Until the end of the string.
```

If you allow underscores with your other characters, it can be simplified to: `^\w[\w'?]*$`

Comment: Right you are. Edited accordingly. It would still work, of course, but this is definitely cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^[a-z\d][a-z\d'?]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This would match just as you say:
Starts with: any letter from the alphabet or a digit.
Until the end it can contain: any letter from the alphabet, a digit, ' or ? characters.

Comment: you have an extra \w in that first part, no?

Comment: Warning: `[a-Z]` is NOT the same as `[a-zA-Z]`. The ranges are simple ASCII and there are characters between `z` and `A`.

Comment: Also be aware that `\w` and `\d` match **Unicode** letters and digits, not just the ASCII characters the OP specified.

Comment: Wow, I don't know what went wrong but I must've fallen asleep while writing that ;) Corrected.

Comment: `<Nitpicking>` @Max `[a-Z]` is wrong even if you want to allow the characters between upper and lowercase letters. `A-z` would be the correct one in that case. (A is 65, a is 97).`</Nitpicking>`

Comment: @Amarghosh: Right. I was concentrating on the obvious problem and missed the larger one.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9?']*$
```

This would even allow strings of length one. To specify a minimum and maximum lengths, change the regex to:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9?']{minlen-1,maxlen - 1}$
```

For example, the following allows strings of length five to 10.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9?']{4,9}$
```